# Is C++ a "waste of time"?

Tags: c++

I ran into this supposed interview of Bjarne Stroustrup, the inventor of C++.

http://artlung.com/smorgasborg/Invention_of_Cplusplus.shtml

> **Stroustrup**: Well, it's been long enough, now, and I believe most people have figured out for themselves that C++ is a waste of time but, I must say, it's taken them a lot longer than I thought it would...
>
> **Interviewer**: Yes, but C++ is basically a sound language.
>
> **Stroustrup**: You really believe that, don't you?  Have you ever sat down and worked on a C++ project?  Here's what happens: First, I've put in enough pitfalls to make sure that only the most trivial projects will work first time.  Take operator overloading.  At the end of the project, almost every module has it, usually, because guys feel they really should do it, as it was in their training course.  The same operator then means something totally different in every module.  Try pulling that lot together, when you have a hundred or so modules.  And as for data hiding, God, I sometimes can't help laughing when I hear about the problems companies have making their modules talk to each other.

Is this a hoax? Do any of these points seem true for any of the veteran C++ programmers out there?

Comment: Depending on mood of the moment .. everything can be a 'waste of time', and things like commenting on SO can be use of time ...

Comment: Snopes or it didn't happen :) ... in other words I think it's safe to assume this is a joke/hoax by someone, given its appearance on a page called "random stuff" and the backstory that it was supposedly suppressed from publication.

Comment: Don't say that. It's bad mkay?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You just have to check the [Stroustrup's website (the FAQ part)](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#IEEE) to find that it's wrong - a well known hoax as Judah Himango already pointed :

> **Did you really give an interview to IEEE?**
>
> in which you confessed that C++ was
>   deliberately created as an awful
>   language for writing unmaintainable
>   code to increase programmers'
>   salaries? Of course not. [Read the
>   real IEEE interview.](http://www.stroustrup.com/ieee_interview.html)

Comment: Thanks for definitive proof of hoax.

Answer (score 40):

It's a [well-known hoax](http://jimmod.blogspot.com/2007/01/interview-with-bjarne-stroustrup-hoax.html).

And no, learning C++ isn't a waste of your time, something that's been discussed on StackOverflow many times.

Comment: That link only says "(hoax)" but doesn't explain anything else.

Comment: scroll to the bottom of the link - it's a spoof

Answer (score 27):

As mentioned, this is a well-known hoax.

But it does provoke some interesting points. These days C++ is a waste of time, except for when you can't afford to waste time. Less opaquely: C++ is a waste of **development time**, except for when you can't afford to waste **execution** time.

Comment: for execution time, C could be better

Comment: C is better in some cases, C++ in others. But C++ is more expressive (see http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1539), unless it's done badly and obfuscated

Comment: @dcw and virtually everything else is more expressive than C and C++. It's always tragic to see a "C++ is bad" thread degrade to "well it's better than C" as though that were saying something...

Answer (score 6):

From the article titled "The Real Stroustrup Interview" in IEEE Computer Magazine Vol. 31 Issue 6 pp.110-114 (June 1998):

> For the past few months, a hoax interview between Stroustrup and Computer has been making the rounds in cyberspace. While we regret the incident, it offers us a welcome opportunity to have the father of C++ share his insights on Standard C++ and software development in general. We can also attest to his continued sense of proportion and humor—he suggests that the ﬁctitious interview would have been a much funnier parody had he written it himself.

Answer (score 5):

As others mentioned, this Interview is hoax.

Well, I am one of the persons who hate C++ and normally doesnt use it, but learning it was definitely not a waste of time. At least now I know why I hate C++ and I understand why other persons use this language and think it is good.

If you want to learn this language to know about its concepts, its benefits and its drawbacks, to be able to read code written in it, and in general to be able to "talk about" it, it is never a waste of time. Same for any other programming language. It will increase your expierience. For example, C++ shows one common way of OOP - a way I dont like, but a way many other people use.

But if you want to learn it because "the people say that it is the best" (as I sometimes read), then it is really a waste of time. Same for any other programming language.

Answer (score 3):

Programmers that feel attracted to higher level languages that take care of memory management and other tasks for them, could feel that C++ is a waste of time.
It certainly is if you can achieve the same goal with another language in less time and with less bug fixing and don't mind the downsides as efficiency.
But I don't regret having learned and spent so many hours coding in C/C++ for it's such a beautiful language and allows you to produce things that not many other languages can.

I mean, don't you want to use the language with which operating systems and compilers are written? that's not a waste of time at all from my perspective.

Comment: I'm aware that the body of the question is centered on whether the Stroustrup's quote is a hoax or not, but nevertheless the title goes *Is C++ a “waste of time”?*

Answer (score 2):

There is **not a single** framework which uses all language features of C++. This introduces a huge **inconsistency** to the language's **ecosystem**.

QT is one of the few APIs which I would call a framework (or API for a **lot** of things):
But it defines own string, own array, ...

What's the point of a "standard" library when no one can use it in a portable and compatible way (from the aspect of **interaction** with other APIs)?

I know, there is **boost**, but what is boost compared to an API such as QT? Nothing.

Look at Java: The is the standard Java API, and every "foreign" API uses it, it's all perfectly compatible.

Comment: Well, I'm sure there are several example against my position, but not nearly as many as compared to C++.

Comment: Boost and QT are fundamentally and conceptually different, you're comparing apples to oranges.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is far from being a waste of your time. You'll understand valuable concepts that will help you understand many other concepts in different programming languages. I.E.: VTABLE.

Comment: C++ defines no such thing as a vtable, that's an implementation detail. And how is it relevant to other languages?

Comment: C++ is a series of workarounds stemming from a poor original design (or at least a design that sacrifices all practical concerns for backwards compatibility with C). If you need to learn practical programming concepts, check out Ada. If you need to learn how a computer works, try assembly.

Answer (score 0):

C++ (and Java) probably the best language to learn to understand concepts of OOP. 
I remember learning it in college benefited me a lot.

Comment: There are soooo many better languages for learning OOP, Ada, Java, C#, Python, Go, etc. C++ has so many "gotchas" that a newbie programmer might conflate C++'s necessary workarounds with real OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Stroustrup is not that stupid to say that! It is definitely a hoax!

Comment: IMHO Stroustrup and "stupid" should not belong together in one sentence.